# Como quebrar linha entre as tags php com css

Tags: php, css

Preciso quebrar linhas entre as tags `php` utilizando o `css` do `figcaption`, uma vez que no `html5` a tag `<br>` está obsoleta.

Meu código:

```
<figcaption>
<?php echo $tiporesultado; ?>
<?php echo $imovelpara; ?>
<?php echo "R$" . number_format($priceimovel, 2, ',', '.') ?>
</figcaption>
```

Falaram que o `clear:both` dava certo, mas nada.

```
figure.imoveisdestaquesguarapari figcaption{
  clear: both;
}
```

Só que quando executa ele fica na mesma linha, preciso que cada tag `php` seja exibida em uma linha. No meu caso, tenha 3 linhas.

Comment: Não seria `display: block;`?

Comment: @Inkeliz Não deu certo.

Comment: Agora que vi, se são três textos dentro que estão junto. Você usa `<br>`  em cada linha para pular linha, ou você pode criar vários parágrafos usando `<p></p>` ou então `<div></div>` para cada um. *Até onde eu saiba o `<br>` não está obsoleto, [aqui tem exemplos de usos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) e [nada consta aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), apenas o atributo `clear` está obsoleto.*

Comment: Qual a fonte que afirma que a tag `br` está obsoleta no HTML 5?

Comment: @Gladison use a tag `<br>` mesmo. Ela não está obsoleta. Acredito que você tenha lido errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei de onde você tirou isso, mas o `<br>` não está obsoleto. Exemplo de utilização no seu código:

```
<figcaption>
<?php echo $tiporesultado."<br>"; ?>
<?php echo $imovelpara."<br>"; ?>
<?php echo "R$" . number_format($priceimovel, 2, ',', '.')."<br>" ?>
</figcaption>
```

Comment: O caractere `\n` não afetará o HTML. Precisa ser o elemento `<br>` mesmo.

Comment: O `/n` Não funcionou. Mas o `<br>` está obsoleto no `html5`. Qual a solução?

Comment: @Gladison Note que não é `/n` e sim `\n`

Comment: Correto, eu coloquei `\n` e nada.